# ShowCaseView layout is messed up on smaller screens

Tags: android, android-layout, showcaseview

I've found the miraculous ShowCaseView library, and everything is okay except this:

[image: Screenshot]

Apparently the screen is too short to place correctly the textview between the button and the showcase circle.

How did you solve this problem?

Comment: use a style and make the text a smaller size

Comment: already tried, the text is smaller but still vertical (and mostly off screen)

Comment: use `settings > developer options > show layout bounds` and figure out what is taking up the space and reduce it's margins

Comment: Same issue.. any luck?

Comment: have u found a solution already? i'm having the same problem